# Does location.reload(); operate the same way in the major browsers?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, reload

Does `location.reload();` operate the same way in the major browsers?

I have been reading up on the `location.reload();` method on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp). I can clearly see the  "Browser support section" that states that the method is supported on all the browsers listed which is great. However, does it operate the same way on all browsers?

For me, on Safari, Chrome and Firefox, when I use the `location.reload();` method the page is reloaded and the display shows the same page section, or point on the page, as it did before the reload.

Can someone verify that this occurrence happens on all browsers latest versions and that this is expected or point me towards some documentation which states this? Thanks.

Comment: Don't use w3schools (http://www.w3fools.com/), take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload

Comment: For that page section probably u re loading some $_GET data i suppose

Comment: @RhinoDevel: MDN isn't answering his question any more than W3Schools. They both say that it's supported in all the major browsers.

Comment: @adrianmann What do you mean by the "same page section" and how does it differ from the other browsers? What behavior are you hoping for?

Comment: @squint, Same page section, if I am viewing the footer, for example, the page refreshes and shows the bottom of the page as opposed to the top. I am hoping for this behavior. Does it operate the exact same way in all browsers?

Comment: I kind of doubt that you'll be able to expect perfectly consistent behavior upon reloading a page. If you need it, you could probably try to emulate it with JS. Have you tried passing `false` to `.reload()`? It shouldn't make a difference, but who knows.

Comment: @squint Cool, yeah I tried using false but got the same result in the browsers I tested it on. You are right, it is probably not a good idea to rely on the behaviour on the method across all browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the `location.reload();` method reloads the current page **the same way as the reload/refresh button in a browser**. So using `location.reload();` is basically the same as hitting the reload/refresh button on your browser. And for modern browsers, the default behavior of page reload is displaying the same page section as before, so it's easier for viewers to start reading from where they left off.

I have tried `location.reload();` on Firefox, IE and Chrome and all of them seem to reload the same page section as before. But older browsers many refresh the page at show from the top.

Documentation on `location.reload();` can be found here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload

Some more info here: http://devdocs.io/dom/location/reload

Comment: Great answer but which browsers and versions "refresh the page at show from the top"? Is there a definitive list anywhere I wonder?

Comment: @adrianmann I googled about browser refresh references but unfortunately didn't find any declarative documentation. However, from my testing, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera and IE 9+ all reloads pages from the same section. IE older than version 9 may have some incompatibility.

Comment: Wow!, okay I will try IE on my windows at home and talk with some colleagues and if I can verify the above I will accept your answer.